# $(a,b)\!=\!1\!=\!(a,c)\Rightarrow (a,bc)\!=\!1$ [coprimes to $\,a\,$ are closed under products]

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

How do I go about proving this?

If $\gcd(a,b)=1$ and $\gcd(a,c)=1$, then $\gcd(a,bc)=1$. I'm very confused with gcd proofs.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/485013/show-that-gcda-bc-1-if-and-only-if-gcda-b-1-and-gcda-c-1

Comment: A few more related posts:
[How to show that $\gcd(ab,n)=1$ if $\gcd(a,n)=\gcd(b,n)=1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/62072),
[Prove that if $\gcd(a,c)=1$ and $\gcd(b,c)=1$ then $\gcd(ab,c)=1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/288561),
[If $\gcd(a,n) = 1$ and $\gcd(b,n) = 1$, then $\gcd(ab,n) = 1$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/586480).

Answer (score 28):

Using [Bezout's Identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity):

Since there are $x,y,u,v$ so that $\color{#C00000}{ax+by=1}$ and $\color{#00A000}{au+cv=1}$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\color{#C00000}{by}\color{#00A000}{cv}
&=\color{#C00000}{(1-ax)}\color{#00A000}{(1-au)}\\
&=1-a(x+u-axu)\\
\color{#0000FF}{a}(x+u-axu)+\color{#0000FF}{bc}vy
&=1
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, $(\color{#0000FF}{a},\color{#0000FF}{bc})=1$

Comment: I too am curious about the downvote. Btw, why do you rearrange before multiplying the Bezout identities? Perhaps to highlight the interpretation in terms of unit multiplicativity? $ $ i.e. $$\,{\rm mod}\ a\!:\ \ \color{#c00}by\equiv 1\equiv \color{#c00}cv\,\Rightarrow \color{#c00}{bc}yv\equiv 1,\ \ \ {\rm  i.e.}\ \  \color{#c00}{b,c}\ \ {\rm unit}\ \Rightarrow\, \color{#c00}{bc}\ \ \rm unit$$

Comment: How does $a(x+u-axu)+bcvy=1\implies (a,bc)=1$?

Comment: @Witiko: since it is a linear combination of $a$ and $bc$ that equals $1$. If $a$ and $bc$ had a common factor, that common factor would divide any linear combination of $a$ and $bc$.

Comment: @robjohn I only have a question about the final line. So I understand that to get 1-a(x+u-axu) we simply factored out an a. Then we can move the a term to the other side in an attempt to show we have a linear combination of a and bc equal to 1. However where did the +bcvy come from?

Comment: @Lil: each line follows from the one before, and the first line is color coded to the appropriate Bezout identity. The $bcvy$ is simply brought down from the $bycv$ on the line above.

Comment: Is the converse true? That is, If gcd(a, bc) =1, then gcd(a, b) = 1?

Comment: @Cheetaiean: $\gcd(a,b)\mid a$ and $\gcd(a,b)\mid b$. Therefore, $\gcd(a,b)\mid bc$. Thus, $\gcd(a,b)\mid\gcd(a,bc)$. So the answer is "yes".

Answer (score 9):

If you know Euclid's Lemma (if $p$ is a prime number and $p$ divides the product $bc$, then either $p$ divides $b$ or $p$ divides $c$), then you can proceed as follows. Let $d=gcd(a,bc)$ and assume, to arrive at a contradiction, that $d>1$. Let $p$ then be a prime number dividing $d$. Then $p$ divides both $a$ and $bc$, and thus either $p$ divides $b$ or it divides $c$. If $p$ divides $b$, then since it also divides $a$, it follows that $p$ divides $gcd(a,b)=1$, which is absurd. Similarly, $p$ dividing $c$ leads to a contradiction.

Remark: this solution avoids considering the entire prime number decomposition for the given numbers. I find it to be a nice little trick that produces clean proofs.

Comment: Unless the proof of Euclid's lemma uses this result with $a=p$.

Answer (score 5):

More generally $\ \bbox[5px,border:1px solid #c00]{(a,b)(a,c) = (a,bc)}\ $ if $\  \color{#0a0}{(a,b,c)=1},\, $ follows by expanding the product, i.e. $\ (a,b)(a,c) = (aa,ab,ac,bc) = (a\color{#0a0}{(a,b,c)},bc) = (a,bc),\, $  using [GCD polynomial arithmetic](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3635955/242), i.e. the GCD associative, commutative, and distributive laws (explained in the prior link).

OP is special case $\ (a,b)\! =\! \color{#c00}{\bf 1}\! =\! (a,c),\ $ so $\,\color{#0a0}{(a,b,c)\! =\! 1},\ $ so $\  \color{#c00}{\bf 1\cdot 1} = (a,bc)\ $ by above.

**Remark** $ $ Worth emphasis: the common Bezout-based proofs can be [viewed more *conceptually* as:](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3555162/242) **invertibles are closed under product**, via $\,b,c\,$ are coprime to $\,a\!\iff\! b,c\,$ invertible $\!\bmod a,\,$ [by Bezout](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2326680/242). The proof is obvious: $\,\overset{}{bb'}\equiv 1\equiv cc'\Rightarrow\ bc\,\color{#c00}{c'b'}\equiv 1\, $ (i.e. $\,(bc)^{-1}\equiv \color{#c00}{c^{-1} b^{-1}})$.

In fraction language it's obvious $\,1/(bc) \equiv (1/b)(1/c).\,$ So the proof becomes obvious and intuitive after translating the Bezout equations into more *arithmetical* congruence language - being essentially the same as well known inverse or fraction laws.

The above proof by GCD laws is **more general** than proofs using Bezout's linear gcd reprentation, since generally gcds fails to have this form, e.g. in the UFD $\rm\,D = \mathbb Q[x,y]\,$ of polynomials in $\rm\,x,y\,$ with rational coefficients we have $\rm\,gcd(x,y) = 1\,$ but there are no $\rm\,f(x,y),\, g(x,y)\in D\,$ such that $\rm\,x\,f(x,y) + y\,g(x,y) = 1;\,$ indeed, if so, then evaluating the purported Bezout equation at $\rm\:x = 0 = y\:$ yields $\,0 = 1.\,$ Similarly for $\,\gcd(2,x)=1\,$ in the UFD $\rm\,\Bbb Z[x]$.

Further, such GCD arithmetic is simpler than Bezout equation manipulations since it is essentially the *same* as (high-school) polynomial arithmetic  - as explained in the first link above.

Comment: You are kind of assuming what you want to prove...(because now those rules need a proof)

Comment: @chubakueno Not true. Any proof of this will use prior results. But neither this proof (or others posted) "assume what you want to prove".

Comment: To dismiss the purported circularity claim, notice the the linked proofs of the GCD arithmetic laws use only the [GCD Universal Property](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/198801/242) $\,c\mid a,b\iff c\mid\gcd(a,b),\,$ which is proved there (in $\,\Bbb Z)\,$ using only the GCD Bezout equation (or it can be proved directly by induction using the Division algorithm, i.e. Euclidean descent). This property is actually the *definition* of the GCD in more general number systems ([GCD domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GCD_domain)). All the basic properties of the GCD follow from this.

Answer (score 5):

We can take as the *definition* of "$a,b$ are relatively prime" that there are $s,t$ with $1=as+bt$. Then the question becomes: given that$$1=as+bt$$and$$1=as^\prime+ct^\prime$$find $S,T$ with$$1=aS+(bc)T.$$Multiplying by $1$ is a useful trick/technique for questions of this sort.$$1=as+bt=as+\mathbf{1}bt=as+\mathbf{(as^\prime+ct^\prime)}bt$$so$$\begin{align}1&=a(s+cst^\prime)+bc(tt^\prime)\\&=a(s^\prime+bs^\prime t)+bc(tt^\prime).\end{align}$$

The second formula arises from the first by applying $(bc)(ss^\prime)(tt^\prime)$ or shifting the derivation. A single formula invariant under that permutation is

$$1=(as+bt)(as^\prime+ct^\prime)=a(ass^\prime+bts^\prime+cst^\prime)+bc(tt^\prime).$$

The symmetry is nice but the first formulas are smaller.

What I like is that uses nothing more than basic properties of rings so the proof is applicable in many rings.

Comment: The definition of "$a,b$ are relatively prime" is different. If $a,b$ are relatively prime / coprime / co-prime, i.e. $\gcd(a,b)=1$ (greatest common divisor), then by Bézout identity/lemma it follows that there exist $s,t\in\mathbb Z$ such that $as+bt=1$.

Answer (score 4):

Since $a, b$ are relatively prime, there exist integers $x, y$ such that $ax + by = 1$. Multiplying both sides of this equation by $c$, we get $$acx + bcy = c.$$ Letting $d = \gcd(a, bc)$, we see from the equation above that since $d$ is a common divisor of $a$ and $bc$, $d$ also divides $c$ by linearity. Then, since every common divisor of two integers also divides their gcd, $d|\gcd(a, c)$. But $\gcd(a, c) = 1$, so $d$ divides $1$. Because the gcd is nonnegative, it follows that $d = \gcd(a, bc) = 1$.

Answer (score 2):

- $\gcd(a,b)=1$ means what about the prime factors common to both $a,b$?
- same for $\gcd(a,c)$
- what is the prime decomposition of $bc$ if you know what $b$, $c$ decompose as?

Combine all together...

Answer (score 2):

$\gcd(a,b)$ means a and b are relatively prime, this means, there is no other common factor other than 1.

you also know that $$\gcd(a,b) = 2^{\min(a_1,b_1)}.3^{\min(a_2,b_2)}.5^{\min(a_3,b_3)}...$$

Now the 2 equations already imply that $$\min(a_1,b_1) = \min(a_2,b_2)=...= 0$$ (there is no common factor of primes)

also $$\min(a_1,c_1) =\min(a_2,c_2)=... = 0$$

this imply, $$\min(a_1,b_1+c_1)= \min(a_2,b_2+c_2)=...=0$$ as the powers > 0, and adding them cannot be < 0,

This imply a,bc are also relatively prime, hence $$\gcd(a,bc)=2^{\min(a_1,b_1+c_1)}.3^{\min(a_2,b_2+c_2)}...= 1$$

*($\min(a,b)$ represents here minimum value of a,b)*