# Prove that $(a,bc)=1$ if and only if $(a,b)=1$ and $(a,c)=1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have proven the forward direction.
By BeZout's identity: $1=ar+(bc)s$ for some integers $r,s$.
A corollary states that $(a,b) =1$ if and only if $1=ar+bs$ for some integers $r, s$. So we can conclude that $(a,b)=1$ since $1 = ar +b(cs)$ and also that $(a,c)=1$ since $1=ar + c(bs)$.

But I do not know how to prove the reverse direction.

Comment: Hint: multiply the Bezout identities for $\,(a,b),\, (a,c)\,$  to get $\ 1 = a(...) + bc(...)\,\Rightarrow\, (a,bc)= 1.$

Comment: [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/673119/if-gcd-a-b-1-and-gcd-a-c-1-then-gcd-a-bc-1) is very closely related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $(a,b)=1$ and $(a,c)=1$. Then we can write
$$
ra+sb=xa+yc=1.
$$
since this property is equivalent to finding a linear combination of $a,b$ or $a,c$ so that we sum up to $1$. Multiplying this out,
$$
(ra+sb)(xa+yc)=1\cdot 1=1.
$$
When we expand, we'll have a $(sy)(bc)$ term and some other terms depending on $a$. Therefore we have found the required linear combination adding to $1$.

In particular,
$$
(rxa+ryc+sbx)a+(sy)bc=1.
$$

Comment: So I found that there is a proposition that states that for all integers a, b, c (a,bc)|(a,b)(a,c). So I think that since (a,b)(a,c)=1 then (a,bc)|1 so (a,bc)=1. Does that suffice to prove the given statement?

Comment: Certainly. But this way uses what you know already.

Comment: Also, your suggestion does make sense for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $(a,b)=m$. then $a=mk$ and $b=mj$. Then $bc=mjc$. So $m$ divides $bc$ too. meaning $(a,bc)$ is at least m.

You can do the same form $(a,c)=n$