# GCD of three relatively prime pairs

Tags: number-theory

Suppose the $GCD$ of integers $a$, $b$, and $c$ is 1 when taken in pairs, i.e., they are relatively prime.  Prove that $GCD(ab,c)=1$.

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Suppose to the contrary that the gcd is $\ne 1$. Then some prime $p$ divides $ab$ and $c$. Continue.

Comment: Alternately, we can use the Bezout "Identity." But that is less natural.

Comment: Also, permuting $a,b,c$, see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/673119/if-gcda-b-1-and-gcda-c-1-then-gcda-bc-1)

Answer (score 2):

Suppose gcd$(a,b,c)=d$ where $d > 1$. Then by definition $d|a$ and $d|b$. However, this implies that $d$ is a common divisor of both $a$ and $b$ and since $d > 1$, it contradcits that gcd$(a,b)=1$

Answer (score 1):

Let A be the set of prime factors of $a$

Let B be the set of prime factors of $b$

Then A$U$B is the set of prime factors of $ab$

If $gcd(ab,c)  \neq 1$ then a prime factor of $c$ is also a prime factor of $ab$ and so it belongs to the set $AUB$.

Hence it must also belong to either the set A or B (or both).

Therefore $c$ shares a prime factor with either $a$,$b$ or both, contradicting the fact that $gcd(a,b,c) = 1$