# The application of Bezout's identity on $\gcd(a, b) = 1$ and $\gcd(a, c) = 1$, then $\gcd(a, bc) = 1.$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

If $\gcd(a, b) = 1$ and $\gcd(a, c) = 1$, then $\gcd(a, bc) = 1$.

A [proof using Bezout's Identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/673135/767615) was written as follows:

> Using [Bezout's
> Identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity):
>
> Since there are $x,y,u,v$ so that $\color{#C00000}{ax+by=1}$ and
> $\color{#00A000}{au+cv=1}$, we have $$ \begin{align}
>  \color{#C00000}{by}\color{#00A000}{cv}
>  &=\color{#C00000}{(1-ax)}\color{#00A000}{(1-au)}\\ &=1-a(x+u-axu)\\
>  \color{#0000FF}{a}(x+u-axu)+\color{#0000FF}{bc}vy &=1 \end{align} $$
> Therefore, $(\color{#0000FF}{a},\color{#0000FF}{bc})=1$

However, as far as I understand, Bezout's Identity does not work in the converse. In other words, $\color{#FF00FF}{a(k) + bc(j) = 1}$ does not imply $(\color{#0000FF}{a},\color{#0000FF}{bc})=1$.

Do I not understand Bezout's Identity, or does this proof work for some other reason?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $\gcd(a,b)=1$ and $\gcd(a,c)=1$, then $\gcd(a,bc)=1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/673119/if-gcda-b-1-and-gcda-c-1-then-gcda-bc-1)

Comment: It *does* work in the converse. Well, the statement of Bezout's theorem is that the gcd is the smallest positive number that is an integer linear combination of the given numbers, and there's no smaller positive number than $1$.

Comment: @AndréMuchon The link you provided contains the exact proof I was questioning.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Thank you! That clarified Bezout's Identity and answered my question.

Comment: @Zanilen You are welcome!

Comment: *Every* common divisor $d$ of $\,a,bc\,$ also divides $\,a\,k+bc\,j = 1,\,$ including their *greatest* common divisor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This very well does prove what we wanted. If you take a look at the proof of Bezout's theorem, you will notice that the smallest positive value of the expression $\ ax+by$ where all of them are integers is indeed $\ (a, b)$. Hence, if the value of the expression can be equal to the smallest positive integer, then $\ (a, b)=1$. I hope it answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

Any time $ax+by=1$, we have $(x,y)=1$.  For if $c\mid x\land c\mid y$, then $c \mid (ax+by)=1$.

That's actually the easy direction.  Bezout's is the harder direction.