# Find all pairs of co-primes $x,y$ such that $\frac{5y^2}{x^2-xy}$ is a square

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find all pairs of natural coprime numbers for which $\sqrt{\frac{5y^2}{x^2-xy}}$ is a natural number.

My approach is that for it to be natural $x^2-xy \mid 5y^2$ so then $x$ is either $1$ or $5$. Then when $x=1 , y$ is either $0,-4,2$ or $6$. I'm not sure which one of these values I should choose.

Comment: Your condition is not sufficient. You must have that $5y^2 = x(x-y)z^2$ for some natural number $z$.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: @PierreCarre would it work if I have $5y^2=x(x-y)z$

Comment: @Student Only if $z$ is the square of something, this is why I proposed $z^2$ right from the start.

Comment: I understand, thank you.

Comment: @AnneBauval $x = 5$ and $y=4$ works just fine.

Comment: @AnneBauval They don't need to be prime, just co-prime.

Comment: I added an answer that should make the proof "obvious" (and highlights the key role played by coprimality and Euclid's Lemma).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We must have that $5y^2 = x(x-y)z^2$ for some natural number $z$. Since $x,y$ are co-primes, $x$ must be either 1 or 5. Since $x=1$ does not work (substitute and see), we conclude that $x$ must be 5. Looking at the resulting condition, $y^2 = (5-y) z^2$, we just need to try values of $y$ smaller than 5.

Comment: Oops sorry I missed that (+1)

Comment: Note: as in the question, the argument implicitly uses Euclid's Lemma (or equivalent), i.e. $(x,y)=1\Rightarrow (x,y^2)=1\,$ so $\,x\mid 5y^2\Rightarrow x\mid 5\ \ $

Comment: I added an answer which highlights the key role of $\rm\color{#c00}{Euclid's\ Lemma} \ $

Answer (score 1):

Note $\,x(x\!-\!y)\mid py^2$ so $\,x\!=\!p,\,x\!-\!y\!=\!1\,$ by $(x,y)\!=\!1$ and below (OP has $\,p\!=\!5)$.

**Theorem** $\,ab\mid pc\,\Rightarrow\, a\!=\!p,\, b\!=\!1\,$ if $\,a\!>\!b\!>\!0\,$ are coprime to $\,c\,$ and $\,p\,$ is prime.

**Proof** $ $ By coprimality and Euclid's Lemma $\,a,b\mid p\,$ so $\,a\!=\!p,\,b\!=\!1\,$ by $\,a\!>\!b\!>\!0$.

Comment: Therefore the quotient $\,pc/ab = c\,,$ so it is a square simply because $c = y^2$ is a square in the OP. $ $ Notice $\,(x,y)\!=\!1\,\Rightarrow\,x,\,x\!−\!y\,$
 are coprime to $\,y\,$ so coprime to $\,y^2,$
 again by Euclid (or [by gcd laws](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/673192/242)). $\ \ $

Comment: Thank you . so y has to be a prime number smaller than 5 right?

Comment: @Student OP has $p=5$ so by the Theorem we get $x=5,\,x-y=1\Rightarrow y = 4.\,$ You don't need to search for $y$ as in the other answer.

Comment: Thank you so much!