# Find gcd of two multivariate polynomials

Tags: gcd-and-lcm

Is there a simple way to find the $\gcd$ of $x^2y$ and $xy^2+1$?

I tried adding multiples of $x^2y$ to the other and vice-versa but I found no easy way to find the gcd. For another example I found $(xy,x^3y+1)=(xy,x^3y+1-x^3y)=1$ by adding $-x^2$ of the first to the second.

Comment: Well, it would have to be a divisor of $x^2y$ and there aren't very many of those.

Comment: Since $x$ and $y$ are coprime to $xy^2+1$ so too is the product $x^2 y$, by [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/673192/242) in the linked dupe. $\ \ $

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Buchberger's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buchberger%27s_algorithm) to find such a polynomial if it exists. The algorithm is suited to find sets of generating multivariate polynomials for a given ideal, the so called [Gröbner bases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6bner_basis#Algorithms_and_implementations).

Comment: Not an answer, and serious overkill for such a simple problem.