# If $\gcd (a,b)=1$, and $\gcd(a,c)=1$, then $\gcd (a,bc)=1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $\gcd (a,b)=1$, and $\gcd(a,c)=1$, then $\gcd (a,bc)=1$
Help proving this? I'm really confused how to go about it..

Comment: Try writing $1=ax+by ; 1=as+(bc)t$, multiplying the two and combining terms in a convenient way.

Comment: There are many ways to prove this, what we need to know is what tools you've been given to use.

Answer (score 3):

By user99680's hint, we apply the [Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic) to prove this statement.

Assume that $\gcd(a,b) = 1$ and $\gcd(a,c) = 1$.  That is: for some integers $s$ and $t$,
$$as + bt = 1$$

and for some integers $u$ and $v$,
$$au + cv = 1$$

Multiply both equations to get
$$\begin{aligned}
(as + bt)(au + cv) &= 1\\
as(au) + as(cv) + au(bt) + cv(bt) &= 1\\
a(asu + scv + ubt) + (bc)vt &= 1
\end{aligned}$$

Assign arbitrary constants for $(asu + scv + ubt)$ and $vt$, say $x$ and $y$.  Thus, we have

$$ax + (bc)y = 1$$

Therefore $\gcd(a,bc) = 1$

Comment: how do we know that those $x, y$ give the minimum linear combination? because they give 1? If for example we had $\gcd(a,b) = g \wedge \gcd(a,c) = 1$ would $\gcd(a, bc) = g$ with the same proof hold?