# Is it true that if $\gcd(a,b) = 1$ and $\gcd(a,c) = 1$ then $\gcd(ac,b) = 1$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

> Is it true that if $\gcd(a,b) = 1$ and $\gcd(a,c) = 1$ then $\gcd(ac,b) = 1$?

I know that $\gcd(a,b) = 1$ means that there exist integers $m$ and $n$ such that
$am + bn = 1$

Same thing for $\gcd(a,c)$: we have $ax + cy = 1$.

But how can I relate this to $\gcd(ac,b)$?

Comment: Not true - just choose $c=b>1$

Comment: If you want a specific non-trivial example, let a=3, b=4, and c=10. Note that b and c share 2 as a common factor.

Comment: Maybe the conclusion is supposed to be $\gcd(a,bc)=1$?

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/485013/show-that-gcda-bc-1-if-and-only-if-gcda-b-1-and-gcda-c-1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $a=2, b=c=3$. Then $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(a,c)=1$ and $\gcd(ac,b)=3$.

You can prove that $\gcd(a,bc)=1$, however.